# How to enable Free text for Combo Box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How can we enable the free text entry for combo box in WPF?
I tried with IsEditable="True", but even that is not working...

my xaml syntax is:
`<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CountryValue, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CountryValues, Mode=OneWay}"></ComboBox>`

Comment: You should bind against `Text="{Binding CountryValue}"`. `SelectedValue` won't work if `IsEditable="True"`.

Comment: Or bind against SelectedItem if you just use IsEditable to AutoComplete the input in the combobox, so you will get the original object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found this on the web:
[Link](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/07/12/How-can-I-allow-users-to-edit-text-in-a-ComboBox-in-WPF.aspx)

```
<Window x:Class="LearnWPF.EditableComboBox.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="LearnWPF.EditableComboBox" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
  <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="items" XPath="//item">
      <x:XData>
        <items >
          <item>01</item>
          <item>02</item>
          <item>03</item>
        </items>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
      <ComboBox IsEditable="True" DataContext="{StaticResource items}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @singla - I copied this code and for me it works fine. the combobox is editable.

Comment: @singla - try copying the code exactly. It really should work. By the way: what error / exception does it give you?

Comment: @Christian- Actually I have applied the Style on the combobox. And that style was making the combo box readonly. now its working properly.

Comment: @singla - That makes sense. Styles can override properties of your controls, which makes it hard to find where those properties were set. What is really really helpful in such cases is a tool called Snoop. You can download Snoop from http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Link is broken.